# Account blocked on pending interaction hangzhounet

Tags: operation, wallets, error, account

as tittle says, my account got stuck at a pending interaction/operation, the hash of the operation doesnt exist when searching it on explorer, i can see the pending operation on temple wallet, umami doesnt even load the operation list it gives an error on index 1.

tz1LgP5DCcgBZ6AaHQw5iwDynCi21G9MKXxy

opaG5fxpjsg4PMrLiXGFPaPiXtTuHh513hLaBej2f7DzkZaU9pu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hangzhounet` is deprecated (Mainnet is running the `Ithaca` protocol). You should try on `Ithacanet` or `Jakartanet`.

Some public nodes:

- https://visualtez.com/nodes
- https://smartpy.io/nodes

Comment: Thanks i just did it following your advise.